# How can I separate the lines in this formula?

Tags: equations

I'm trying to write the following formula on different lines due to its length. I did the following:

```
\begin{multiline}
\(d_{m}^{\Theta}(C_{k\textbackslash}{p_{i}},f)=\sqrt[m]{\underline{|-f(p_{i})|^{m}-|1-f(p_{i})|^{m}} \\
+\sum_{i=1}^{length(C_k)}|C_k(i)-f(i)|^{m}}\)
\end{multiline}
```

Provided that I have used `\usepackage{amsmath}`

You can see that I have used `\\` to separate the lines. But, this didn't work. What could I be missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: the environment in `multline` not `multiline` (Please always show error messages)

Comment: Also, you shouldn't have `\( ... \)` inside `multline`, the latter is a math environment.

Answer (score 2):

Your input has several errors:

1. the environment is called `multline`
2. `\(` and `\)` should not appear inside it
3. several braces are not matched up correctly

Here is a possibly correct version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
d_{m}^{\Theta}(C_{k\setminus\{p_{i}\}},f)=\sqrt[m]{\underline{|-f(p_{i})|^{m}-|1-f(p_{i})|^{m}}} \\
+\sum_{i=1}^{\operatorname{length}(C_k)}|C_k(i)-f(i)|^{m}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]